# maven-bundle-plugin:4.1.0:install on jenkins hangs

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-bundle-plugin

On Jenkins, maven-bundle-plugin:4.0.0:install (default-install) hangs without any further output.

I've checked the logs, tried -X -e option and tried the 4.1.0 version of the plugin.

Everything runs fine if I execute Maven locally.

It used to run on Jenkins for years.

I think it behaves like this since I've updated a couple of Jenkins plugins.

What could be the cause?

**Update**

I guess it has something to do with OBR.
From a successfull call:

> ### --- maven-bundle-plugin:4.1.0:install (default-install) @ myProject
>
> Installing `<myProject-jar-path>`
>
> Writing OBR metadata

ObrInstall is bound to "install":

https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/felix/releases/maven-bundle-plugin-4.1.0/src/main/java/org/apache/felix/obrplugin/ObrInstall.java?view=markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I could find the source of the issue: the .m2/repository/repository.xml seems to have been corrupted.

I've deleted the whole .m/repository directory (after I've backuped it first).

Everything works fine again.

Comment: I recommend to read: https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/